# Add Multiple Product Attributes using Shortcode in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For my wordpress webiste, I have used the code below to add a shortcode to display the "processor" product attribute in my product page however I can't figure how to add more attributes, can someone help me?

```
//Shortcode to output product attribute
function product_list_attribute_func( $atts ){  
    
    global $product;
    
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'name' => 'processor',
    ), $atts );
    
    if( is_string( $atts['name'] ) ){
        //get attribute
        $prod_attribute = $product->get_attribute( $atts['name'] );
        return $prod_attribute;
    }   
}
add_shortcode('product_list_attribute', 'product_list_attribute_func');
```

Comment: there are several solutions to this problem. You could make more attributes, you could make it into an array, or a comma separated string. and then change your code to work with that.

Comment: Do you want this to output only one attribute at a time,  for example one call outputs the name and another outputs the price>?  Like a Gitter kind of thing if that makes sense?

Comment: I have same eight attributes for every product on my page. I want all the eight attributes to show in an unordered list. For example: 1st Attribute is Processor and 2nd is Ram, so I want the following output: • Processor: Intel Celeron in one line and • Ram: 8GB in second line and so on

Comment: You'll have to return the unorderd list as html then.   Basically build a list of attributes in $atts - then loop over that array and create the list and then return the html to wordpress.  The `shortcode_atts` function you can think of like array merge, it just fills in some default values if they are missing.  Without all the attributes I can't really do a full example.  It's pretty strait forward though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this based on your comment

```
//Shortcode to output product attribute
function product_list_attribute_func( $atts ){  
    
    global $product;

    if(!$product) return ''; //bail if there is no product
    
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'processor' => $product->get_attribute('processor'), // I think this is what you were probably most confused about
         'graphics' => $product->get_attribute('graphics')
        //other attributes here
    ), $atts );
    // the default product attributes will get replaced by what is in the shortcode 
   
   //remove this optional one from the array if empty
   if(empty($atts['graphics'])) unset($atts['graphics']);

   //$atts = array_filter($atts, fn($a)=>$a); //remove all empty atts '', 0, false, null etc..

    //turn on output buffering
    ob_start(); ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($atts as $k => $v ):?>
        <ol> <?php echo $k;?> - <?php echo $v; ?></ol>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <ul>
    
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean(); //return the buffered output
}
add_shortcode('product_list_attribute', 'product_list_attribute_func');
```

I use output buffering because I like the way it colors it in my editor, it's fine to use strings or whathave you as well.  I just like the actual HTML formatting better for readability.

Also I think you are going to want to add the product's attributes in your list of attributes as the defaults, then whatever is put in the shortcode for those attributes could be replaced.

Also there is no guarantee that a product will be available as a global, depending how the shortcode is used.  Normally this will cause an error something like `trying to call a method on bool` or something like that. We should handle this and either return an empty string as output or if you choose, you could throw an exception with a better description. Something like `throw new Exception('this shortcode can only be used with a product')` Ideally this wouldn't be used outside of the scope you intend but it could be used in a post or something without a product being loaded first.

cheers

Comment: Hello, I tried this method and I think there is some problem. There are different types of processor for different products that I have added using Woocommerce. For the code I shared, the second part of function fetched the processor type from for the said product. But now I instead of getting for say "Intel Celeron" automatically I am getting "Processor" as it is. I am sorry if I am unable to explain clearly. English isn't my first language so please excuse me for this.

Comment: Try this `[product_list_attribute]`  and change where it says `name` to `processor`  in the code -- You asked for a unordered list of product attributes.  ( Update I changed this for you )

Comment: you could do `[product_list_attribute processor="xyz"]` to change what it is otherwise it's default of the global product and what attributes you put in the list.  This would say `xyz` for the processor.  I thought the `name` was literally `processor`  not that the name represented the attribute.  Or in other words that it was the `name` attribute literally.

Comment: Thank you, the edited code works perfectly. There is just a small error in line 16, you can change for future reference if someone wants to find the same. It should be $atts instead of $attrs. Thank you for the code.

Comment: sure I will update it thanks.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure if this is the right place to ask. The code works perfectly as of now, but I am planning to add more attributes in future that are not going to be present for all the products. For Example: If I add "Graphics" attribute for some products and then use the code given above, for the products that do not have the graphics attribute the following line still shown: "Graphics :". Is there any way to hide this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253540/discussion-between-nishit-agrawal-and-artisticphoenix).

Comment: It depends if you care about empty values, if you don't than you can simply filter the array using `array_filter` for empty values.  Otherwise you can check if a specific key is empty and then remove it from the array - before the loop.  It looks like WOO returns an empty string when the product doesn't exist.  No value no attribute ...   I'll update it with an example using `graphics`